# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ebank.rajeev.controllers.Alogin

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm getting this error on eclipse console,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ebank.rajeev.controllers.Alogin
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

On running the jsp page, tomcat says
HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.

My code is correct. Still I'm unable to find a way.

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Alogin</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Alogin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>Alogin</display-name>
<servlet-name>Alogin</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.ebank.rajeev.controllers.Alogin</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

admin.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="Alogin">
<div>
<input type="password" name="uname" placeholder="username" />
<input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password" />
<input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="Login" /><br />
</div>
</form>
```

Alogin servlet

```
String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
    String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");
    if(uname.equals("admin") && pwd.equals("admin"))
    {
         HttpSession session=request.getSession();
         session.setAttribute("UNAME",uname);
         response.sendRedirect("AdminHome.jsp");
    }
    else
    {
         response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp?msg=invalid");
    }
```

Java build path has required jar files, i.e., `servlet-api.jar`, `jsp-api.jar`, `mysql-connector.jar`. I'm using any sql code for this page still it is giving the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Project Properties and on `Deployment Descriptor`, add `Java Build path entries` and a reference to your source folders, usually `/src/main/resources` to `WEB-INF/classes`. Do `Project`>`Clean` and restart the server.

Comment: I've done all that many a times. All Java Build path entries are added in the deployment assemble for the project properties. I've also reinstalled Tomcat, Eclipse many a times. Created a new project. Nothing helped.

Comment: What happens when you try to create the instance or refer class `com.ebank.rajeev.controllers.Alogin` in any of your project files?

Comment: Creating the instance for the class Alogin is working in other class file.

Comment: Alright @Rajeev. Do export of project as `war`, open the `war` with any archive utility and let me know if you see `Alogin.class` in `WEB-INF\classes\<your_package_to_alogin_servlet>`

Comment: Alogin.class is present in the said directory path.

Comment: Could you remove the mentioned `servlet-api.jar` and add `Server Runtime` referring to your server in the build path? Also, go to your `Alogin.java`, right click on the class name and `Copy qualified name`, paste it in the `servlet-class` part of `web.xml`?

Comment: Removed servlet-api.jar and added apache tomcat v8.0 server runtime. Now the index.jsp or any other jsp page is giving 404 error

Comment: We will figure it out @Rajeev, could you copy paste the qualified name to `web.xml`? Also recommend you to `Project`>`Clean` after done with the changes and then restart the server.

Comment: I think there's problem with the server. I removed v8 and used v7 with the old project having sane code and it worked. Now configuring the tomcat v7 for the current prefect it says, tomcat v7 only supports j2ee 1.2,1.3,1.4 and java ee5 and 6 web modules. What does this mean?

Comment: When you go to `Project Facets` in the the project properties, the version of `Dynamic Web Module` matters with servers. If it is not supported, you would need to delete the project without purging the files, delete eclipse specific settings folders inside the project and do an import of project with lower version of `Dynamic Web Module` compatible to the current server.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `com.ebank.rajeev.controllers.Alogin` class will not be present in the jars you mention. You have to review what third libraries are required in your project.

If you have a bunch of libraries, and you don't know where is `com.ebank.rajeev.controllers.Alogin` provided, then you can use jarscan a great tool to find the appropriate jar.

You can download jarscan from here http://www.oracle.com/splash/java.net/maintenance/index.html

And use it in this way:

```
java -jar jarscan.jar -d /path/to/find/libraries -j com.ebank.rajeev.controllers.Alogin
```

Comment: I've package com.ebank.rajeev.controllers under src folder. Alogin is the servlet inside the package. 
How to add this class into jars.? Or what should I do?

Comment: well, then your problem is that you are not packaging correctly your project. Your java sources have to compiled into `WEB-INF/classes` or packaged into a jar library that have to be copied into `WEB-INF/lib`. Review your project configuration.

Comment: So how can I do that? How the source can be compiled into web-inf/classes or the other thing you mentioned.

Comment: It really depends on how are you using eclipse. Is your project a dynamic web project? Is your project a maven project? ...? James instructions are right, but it is impossible for us to know how are you project managed.

Comment: It's a dynamic web project. I've done what James had said before posting question here.

Comment: Please, export your project as a war file, open the war with zip utility and see if you find your Alogin class inside `WEB-INF/classes` in the expected path, that is `com/ebank/rajeev/controllers`. If this is correct, then your project is right and you have a problem with tomcat. If the class is not present, the problem is with your project. Tell us.

Comment: Yes, Alogin.class and Alogin.java file is present inside the war file web-inf/classes/..../controllers

Comment: Then eclipse is not deploying your app into tomcat. Try to remove tomcat runtime from eclipse and start again.

Comment: In that case i can't give you an aswer without check your eclipse, project and tomcat installation. It is quite clear where you problem comes from, classpath problem, but can't help you, sorry.